# Floated divs using % widths with a min/max width and 100% height (Responsive)

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, one needs to be a fixed width, the other responsive to the users device. Currently when below a certain width the floated divs jump onto separate lines. Is there a way to...

1) Make them both 100% height of the body

2) Stay on the same lines so the right side div can shrink in width while the left side div retains it's min/max width?

Also the right div at 70% never fills up the full 70% of space available.

I realise what I'm trying to do is a bit of a oxymoron but can't think of a way around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/establish/fxQfv/

**HTML**

```
<article>
</article>

<section>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
article  { 
background: blue;
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 30%;
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 200px;
}

section  { 
background: red;
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 70%;
}
```

​
​

Comment: The reason the two blocks don't fill up the whole page is because you have max-width set on article. Though you have the width set to 30%, the max-width will never allow the width to pass 200px. This means that because section only takes up 70% of the width, there will always be extra white space assuming that 30% of the page width is more than 200px.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do realise this, hence my oxymoron comment, I was open to any new suggestions.

Comment: Looks like you found your answer below, just wanted to make sure you understood what was going on with the max-width :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fxQfv/3/

```
article  { 
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

section  { 
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
```

For your height problem take a look at this article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/
​

Comment: So simple! Thanks. Guess I don't even need the 30% anymore

Comment: Works but this is very static.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is these two lines:

```
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 200px;
```

They contradict this line:

```
width: 30%;
```

The `section` will always be 70% of the width, but the `article` is always `200px`.  If you remove those two lines it will work.

If you need the article to be `200px`, the section should be `width: auto`, although I don't know if that behavior is guaranteed in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I feel you misunderstood my initial question though

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your idea can be achieved using the two elements separately. Instead I would put the `<article>` into the `<section>`, and then making the section

```
section  {
width: 100%;
}​
```

This way, the the `<section>` will always fit the row, and the `<article>` can still be of a fixed width.
Also, you don't need to enter the percent width for `<article>`, as setting `max-width = max-height` will replace it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fxQfv/4/